# Is firefox "send tab" supposed to work instantly?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has an option for sharing links between devices where you're using firefox and are logged into the same mozilla account.

I expect it to be instant, but it seems to me either I'm misunderstanding the feature or that there is something wrong with my setup, because I see the tab appear hours after sending it. The sending device is a linux desktop and receiving device an android phone. This happens even with the application open and battery saver disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's janky.

The tab is sent instantly, but the other end doesn't receive it immediately. You can manually trigger Firefox account sync, it will cause sent tabs to appear.

For a more reliable alternative consider Pushbullet.

Comment: I'm trying to sync ~100 tabs in 3 windows from one PC to another. Been screwing around w/ Mozilla's useless docs & help for 2 hours when I saw this - it was a revelation! So I've been "partially" successful, but only getting a small fraction of my tabs sync'd. `Pushbullet` seems to work only from PC-to-phone. I need PC-to-PC. Any ideas??

Comment: @Seamus Sync is different than sending tabs. Sending opens a tab instantly or notifies you about it being sent. Sync lets you view what tabs are open on other devices in the menu, but doesn't open them immediately.

Comment: Yes - thank you for the clarification. In this case, I feel it's the same concept (sync-ing and send-ing) really, but I may have used the term incorrectly. Semantics aside, after more than 24 hours, I've yet to see sync open all the tabs on a second PC. However, I did finally solve the issue, and [posted an answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1687263/907399) - any feedback will be appreciated. That said, your answer was helpful to me as it disabused me of my assumption that the synced tabs would appear on another PC reliably and quickly.